# split string on each line of file

Tags: powershell, split

I'm trying to split each line in a text file and output all text beyond the split (on text "TransactResponse") to another file (ref.txt):

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\batches\XpRef\System.*.log | ForEach-Object -Process { $ split("TransactResponse")[1], "multiline" } | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Desktop\batches\XpRef\ref.txt
```

No text to output file is generated when I run this script.

Comment: inside a foreach loop, you reference the current element with `$_` but in your code you only use `$` (without the underscore). You also have an error around *split* : you will have to use -split (powershell way ) or .split (.net way)

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above.
A sample code :

```
$s=gc C:\temp\t.txt
$s -split 'TransactResponse' | where {$_}
```

(the where clause will filter empty lines )

Comment: Thank you Kayasax, both versions (if I append [1] to 'TransactResponse' of your second version) now output what appear to be the same text, but it is not all the text after 'TransactResponse', rather a jumble of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that like this:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\batches\XpRef\System.*.log -ReadCount 1000 |
 ForEach-Object {
 $_ -Match 'TransactResponse' -replace '.*TransactResponse(.+)','$1' |
 Add-Content   C:\Users\Desktop\batches\XpRef\ref.txt }
```

You can omit the `-Match 'TransactResponse'` if all the lines contain that string.